# Alert to check if Update query is being run on MSSQL Database

Tags: sql-server, ssms

Good Day,

I am wondering if its possible to set up an alert that will activate when a user is running UPDATE queries on the database using applications like SQL Server Management Studio or the SQLCMD.exe command line or a custom Dot Net application?

What I want is the users accessing the database only via the approved design application. While we provide MSSQL Client with SSMS to some users to test their queries, I don't want them to be running any UPDATE queries on the database.

I can get a list of users that are connected to the database instance via SSMS by using below query. I would appreciate any advise on this.

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT 
DB_NAME(dbid) as MSSQLDatabase, 
COUNT(dbid) as Number_Of_Connections,
loginame as Logged_User, login_time as Logged_Time,
hostname as Client_Machine, program_name as Client_Application,
hostprocess as Client_AppProcessID  FROM 
sys.sysprocesses  WHERE     dbid > 0  AND program_name like '%Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio%' GROUP BY dbid, loginame, login_time,hostname, program_name, hostprocess
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd, personally, create a log table, and then log details of the Application used via a Trigger. Then, you can have a task set up to email you details of logs in the table, where the Application name isn't that of your Application.

The trigger would simply be something like:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.CheckApp_OnUpdate
   ON  dbo.YourTable
   AFTER UPDATE
AS 
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO YourAlertTable (UserName, LoginName, TableEffected, LogTime, ApplicationName)
    VALUES (CURRENT_USER, SYSTEM_USER, 'YourTable', GETDATE(), APP_NAME());

END
GO
```

Hopefully you know how to send an email from SQL Server based on existing data?

Edit: I don't suggest having a trigger email you the detail.s Using `sp_send_dbmail` in a trigger is a **bad** idea.

Comment: Hi, @Larnu many thanks for quick reply. I will play with this idea to populate a new table. I am familiar with Database Email, so will set that up by running select queries later on that table. I am not a DBA but will try to use your suggestion and hopefully will come up with a solution.